# how to apply back and forth scalling to all objects in fabricJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, fabricjs, scaling

I have multiple canvas in one screen using fabricJS.

I have added some ITexts, Text Box, Image, Background in each canvas.

I have some scalling options, like 25%, 50%, 100% to 300% in increasing order of 25%.

If my current default scale is 100% it means scalefactor is 1, now if I apply 125 or 150 or whatever then it is working fine with this code. but once I go down means 25 or 50 then again 150 or 175. then it starts to behave strange. my code is here. I tried to do scaling based on initial scalefactor but its not working as expected.

```
        const scalefactor = Number(this.selectedScale) / 100;
        this.canvas.forEach((canvas: any, index) => {

            this.canvas[index].setDimensions({
                width: Number(this.canvas[index].originalCanvasWidth * scalefactor),
                height: Number(this.canvas[index].originalCanvasHeight * scalefactor)
            });

            this.canvas[index].setZoom(scalefactor);


            if (this.canvas[index].backgroundImage) {
                // Need to scale background images as well
                let bi = this.canvas[index];
                bi.width = bi.originalBackgroundImageWidth * scalefactor;
                bi.height = bi.originalBackgroundImageHeight * scalefactor;
            }

            let objects = this.canvas[index].getObjects();
            for (let i in objects) {
                const scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
                const scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
                const left = objects[i].left;
                const top = objects[i].top;

                const tempScaleX = scaleX * scalefactor;
                const tempScaleY = scaleY * scalefactor;
                const tempLeft = left * scalefactor;
                const tempTop = top * scalefactor;

                objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
                objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
                objects[i].left = tempLeft;
                objects[i].top = tempTop;

                objects[i].setCoords();
            }

            this.canvas[index].renderAll();
            this.canvas[index].calcOffset();
        });
```

for canvas and background its working fine only for objects its not scalling properly as well as its position is not setting properly.

Comment: I have multiple canvases in this.canvas, that's why I used for loop to apply changes for all canvas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

keep in mind that you need to use the old scale.
Example. you have a canvas of 100px...you scale down to 0.5 (that means 50 px) and after this you apply a scale of 1.5.. the result result should be 150px but instead is 75 because you multiply the scaled canvas.

```
    const scalefactor = Number(this.selectedScale) / 100;
  const oldScaleFactor = Number(this.oldScaleFactor) / 100;  //this.oldScaleFactor should be 100 at the first time
        this.canvas.forEach((canvas: any, index) => {

            this.canvas[index].setDimensions({
                width: Number(this.canvas[index].originalCanvasWidth / oldScaleFactor * scalefactor),
                height: Number(this.canvas[index].originalCanvasHeight / oldScaleFactor * scalefactor)
            });

            this.canvas[index].setZoom(scalefactor);


            if (this.canvas[index].backgroundImage) {
                // Need to scale background images as well
                let bi = this.canvas[index];
                bi.width = bi.originalBackgroundImageWidth / oldScaleFactor * scalefactor;
                bi.height = bi.originalBackgroundImageHeight / oldScaleFactor * scalefactor;
            }

            let objects = this.canvas[index].getObjects();
            for (let i in objects) {
                const scaleX = objects[i].scaleX;
                const scaleY = objects[i].scaleY;
                const left = objects[i].left;
                const top = objects[i].top;

                const tempScaleX = scaleX / oldScaleFactor * scalefactor;
                const tempScaleY = scaleY / oldScaleFactor * scalefactor;
                const tempLeft = left / oldScaleFactor * scalefactor;
                const tempTop = top  / oldScaleFactor * scalefactor;

                objects[i].scaleX = tempScaleX;
                objects[i].scaleY = tempScaleY;
                objects[i].left = tempLeft;
                objects[i].top = tempTop;

                objects[i].setCoords();
            }

            this.canvas[index].renderAll();
            this.canvas[index].calcOffset();
        });
```

Comment: @Maruis: check this property originalCanvasWidth, I have maintained all first properties, which are original. for canvas and background, image scaling is working perfectly. but for objects, texts, images, rect. scaling is not working as expected.

Comment: ok..did you try my solution without the division for canvas  and backgroundImage?

Comment: yes I tried but objects are not scaling properly as well as its position is also not working properly.

Comment: Check here:http://jsfiddle.net/hf5rpsyw/1/. Since you change the canvas dimensions is no need to change the zoom factor of canvas